# how to develop web page with minimum 1024px width, with responsive design for greater than 1024px?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have to develop a web page. All the content of the page will be in outer most div called container.

Minimum size of container div should be 1024 px. Even if the viewport size is less than 1024px container div size should be  1024px.

if the view port size is greater than 1024px then the content should be resized accordingly.

Comment: Use css: `min-width:1024px;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `min-width` property:

```
container {min-width: 1024px; }
```

Comment: Please add some comments to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
/* CSS for 1024px or less */

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
   /* CSS for 1025px and above */
}
```